# Changing the default location of BQ project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When using a script to load data into bigquery, it chooses as default location US. Also if I click create dataset, it says 'default location is currently US multi-region. Apart from manually selecting a different location all the time, is there a way to change this default?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/locations#dataset_location), after you create your dataset, the location can not be changed. However, when creating your dataset you can select the **Data location**, using the *Console*, *Python API* or other languages, as shown [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/datasets#create-dataset).

I should point that every-time you create a dataset you should specify the location. Otherwise, it will use the default `US`.

Comment: Hello @Luuk and welcome to StackOverflow! Please remember to [react to answers for your questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). 
That way we know if the answers were helpful and other community members could also benefit from them. Try to [accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) that is the final solution for your issue, upvote answers that are helpful and comment on those which could be improved or require additional attention. Enjoy your stay!